# Access to real camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make an application that changes what the camera sees for Cardboard for exemple. I've been looking for a few days, but I can not have the main camera background "transparent" and see what the camera sees.

I managed to do it with tutorials but not for Cardboard As soon as I go on the binocular aspect, it does not work anymore.

Do you have any solutions?

(sorry for my english .. ^^ ')

Comment: You don't make the render "transparent" but instead have e.g. a UI rawImage and let the real camera output be rendered on that image... Search for `Unity VideoCapture`

Comment: yes, it's what i understand, use rawImage work for 2D but not for 3D ...

Comment: Did you have a look on e.g. https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Integrating-Cardboard-to-the-ARVR-Sample.html ?